# Drupal 7 - Populate Drop Down select from DB in Form API

Tags: drupal-7, form-api

I am still new to PHP, and even newer to Drupal's Form API. I'm simply trying to populate a drop down select from the database. I think the issue stems from my lack of a deep understanding of how to work with multidimensional arrays. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

My code is currently:

```
    //Query DB for Rows
    $query = db_select('hp_education_years');
    $query->fields('hp_education_years', array('id', 'years',));
    $query->orderBy('years', 'ASC');
    $results = $query->execute();

    //define rows
    $options = array();
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $options[$result->id] = array(
            $result->years,
        );
    }
    $form['education']['year'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Year'),
        '#options' => $options,
        '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="data_set"]' => array('value' => 'education'),
            ),
        ),
    );
```

This returned a populated list, but displays the year's ID in bold as well as the year (2008 for example).

How can I get the dropdown just to display the year, not the year ID in bold, and then the year. It seems like $option is just a level higher than I want it to be? if that makes sense?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing

```
//define rows
$options = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $options[$result->id] = array(
        $result->years,
    );
}
```

to

```
//define rows
$options = array();
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $options[$result->id] = $result->years;
}
```

If you look at the example from [Drupal's Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#select), you'll see that the Options values should be just the string value and not an array.